Download CSV from webpage as text
I want to "get" a CSV file from a webpage in VBA using this code (or similar):
Dim sHTTPResponse As String
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
objHTTP.Open "POST", sURL, False
objHTTP.Send ""
sHTTPResponse = objHTTP.responseText

This code works for a number of websites and pages which do NOT return a CSV file.
But it fails with "access is denied" when the URL points to a Google spreadsheet, like for example:
"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRE5XeARs0iTKboEAfnVbdr-XPq0SUltZ1YGNxFtFcg4Zl6CTjGwk3pg6sUti4wmC0T0TXZsidZCEDP/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv"
Is it trying to write to my disk when it says "access is denied" ? I am only interested in retrieving the file as text in a text string.

Have you looked at what others have found and used on here? If not, you should do. Any solution can be copied and edited to suit your situation.

You can use my function DownloadFile found in module Internet.bas at Github:
VBA.PictureUrl.
Url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRE5XeARs0iTKboEAfnVbdr-XPq0SUltZ1YGNxFtFcg4Zl6CTjGwk3pg6sUti4wmC0T0TXZsidZCEDP/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv"
Result = DownloadFile(Url, "D:\Test\yourfile.csv")


The output parameter &output=csv is causing the error.  Removing the parameter returns HTML as text.  You could convert the text to an html document extract the table data but I think Power Query is the tool for the job.
sURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRE5XeARs0iTKboEAfnVbdr-XPq0SUltZ1YGNxFtFcg4Zl6CTjGwk3pg6sUti4wmC0T0TXZsidZCEDP/pub?gid=0&single=true"

Power Query
The code below will add a query table that automatically refreshes every 5 minutes.  I set it to 5 minutes because the GooGleFinance Spreadsheet says that it is updated every 5 minutes.
Sub CreateGoogleFinanceTable()
    Const QueryName As String = "Google-Finance"
    Const RefreshPeriod As Long = 5
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries(QueryName).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=QueryName, Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRE5XeARs0iTKboEAfnVbdr-XPq0SUltZ1YGNxFtFcg4Zl6CTjGwk3pg6sUti4wmC0T0TXZsidZCEDP/pub?gid=0&single=true""))," & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0, {" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "        {""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", Int64.Type}, {""Column3"", type text}," & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "        {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", type text}," & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "        {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}," & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "        {""Column10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}, {""Column12"", type text}" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "    })," & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#""Changed Type"", [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "    #""Changed Type1"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"", {" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "        {""Google"", type text}, {""Reuters RIC"", type text}, {""Spot"", type number}," & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "        {""Close"", type number}, {""CCY"", type text}, {""Shares"", Int64.Type}," & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "        {""High"", type number}, {""Low"", type number}, {""LastTrade"", type datetime}," & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "        {""Name"", type text}" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "    })," & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "    #""Reordered Columns"" = Table.ReorderColumns(#""Changed Type1"", {" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "        ""Google"", ""Reuters RIC"", ""Spot"", ""Close"", ""CCY"", ""Shares"", ""High"", ""Low"", ""LastTrade"", ""Name""" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "    })," & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "    #""Removed Columns"" = Table.RemoveColumns(#""Reordered Columns"", {""1"", """"})" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "in" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        "    #""Removed Columns"""
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 0"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 0]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = RefreshPeriod
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub


